# How can I animate adding background color with just jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui

jQuery's animate function does not work for background-color. How can I smoothly turn the background color from white to a color without adding jQuery UI or other plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple trick of using fadeIn().

```
$('element').css('background-color','red');
$('element').hide();
$('element').fadeIn(500);
```